# How can I set the inner margins of a Beamer block?

Tags: beamer, margins, beamerposter

I've worked myself into a rut.  A very, *very* hacky, plain-TeX-y rut.

I'm creating a poster with `beamerposter`.  Content is split logically into `block` environments, and customization is done through the hooks beamer provides (`\addtobeamertemplate`).  That's where the LaTeX ends.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0]{beamerposter}
\mode<presentation>{%
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}%
}

\title[short]{Looonnger!!}
\author{me}
\institute{grubby}
\date{\today}

% needed to stretch out title box cleanly, but likely the root of my problem
\setbeamersize{text margin left = -5pt, text margin right = -5pt}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}
  {}
  {\vspace{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex} % Pads top of block
     % separates paragraphs in a block
   \setlength{\parskip}{24pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
   \addtolength{\leftskip}{1em}   %%% awful hack for left/right padding
   \addtolength{\rightskip}{1em}} %%% that doesn't even work right
\addtobeamertemplate{block end}
  {\vspace{2ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}}% Pads bottom of block
  {\vspace{10ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}} % Seperates blocks from each other

\addtobeamertemplate{description item}
  {\hspace{2em}} % trying to compensate for the awful hack
  {}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{}
  \vspace{-8pt}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{}
    \maketitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vspace{10ex}

  \begin{block}{Block A}
    \lipsum

    \begin{description}[longest label]
    \item[short] Short stuff
    \item[long] Longer stuff
    \item[longest label] Longest stuff (insert cat)
    \end{description}

     \begin{itemize}
     \item I'd like to change the margins here, as well.
     \item The macros \texttt{\textbackslash leftskip} and friends
       don't work very well for environment-heavy \LaTeX{} document
       classes such as \texttt{beamer}
     \item Also, for some reason, using \texttt{\textbackslash verb}
       kills \emph{everthing}.
     \end{itemize}  
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and what it produces:
[image: hack]

Note that the bullets/balls for the `itemize` environment are flush with the left margin.  Description environment would do the same thing if it weren't for the explicit customization.  All text also goes way too close to either side; amenable through `\leftskip` but not `\rightskip`.  It's an absolute mess.

My immediate goal is to be able to set the right margin so text doesn't go to close.  My 'better' goal is to set inner padding for block contents so that I won't have to set the margins for each environment individually, which will quickly get out of hand.  And finally, as I said in a comment in the code, I believe the root of my problem is how I stretch out the title to give it a cleaner look (not just a colored block on a white background), but I'm pretty sure that'd be a separate question.

---

*From the comments:*
Briefly, I was aiming for (nothing special) a title whose color spans the entire top of the page and content in blocks where the content is padded by about 2 or 3em to taste.

Comment: It's a bit hard to know what layout you are aiming for, you have negative margins set so it's not surprising the text goes close to the edge (it presumably could have gone wider) setting of `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` by hand just simply isn't supported in latex. LaTeX itself sets those all the time depending on the current justification and/or list structure so any direct setting will either do the wrong thing or get over-written. In general you never set the right margin, you set the left margin and the text length.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I knew `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` were bad ideas from the start, but I didn't think of any other way to do it.  I don't find myself ever needing to mess with margins, at least nothing `geometry` can't handle.  I've never done a poster before. :P  (Also I didn't think about text length! :D Always learning.) --- Briefly, I was aiming for (nothing special) a title whose color spans the entire top of the page and content in blocks where the content is padded by about 2 or 3em to taste.  (I'll edit this in particular into the question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` is doomed to failure when lists are involved.

Say `\usepackage{changepage}` in the preamble and

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}
  {}
  {\vspace{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex} % Pads top of block
     % separates paragraphs in a block
   \setlength{\parskip}{24pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}%
   \begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{2cm}
}
\addtobeamertemplate{block end}
  {\end{adjustwidth}%
   \vspace{2ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}}% Pads bottom of block
  {\vspace{10ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}} % Seperates blocks from each other
```

Remove the `\addtobeamertemplate{description item}` part.

[image]

For `\verb` you have to declare your frame as `fragile`:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
```

I'd also avoid doing

```
\setbeamersize{text margin left = -5pt, text margin right = -5pt}
```

but it's just me.

Comment: I'm probably going to get rid of the `\setbeamersize{...}`, and just deal with the ugliness or find a different theme.  I didn't know about `changepage` though! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a simple way to also make the margins apply to the block title, or is this complicated enough to warrant another question?

Comment: @varkor New question, I'd say.

Answer (score 3):

This gets closer, I still hacked textwidth to get the title box wider, if I knew more beamer that presumably wouldn't be needed. you get `\verb`you have to use `[fragile]` frame option.I added `\verb|$\log$|` somewhere to test.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0]{beamerposter}
\mode<presentation>{%
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}%
}

\title[short]{Looonnger!!}
\author{me}
\institute{grubby}
\date{\today}

% needed to stretch out title box cleanly, but likely the root of my problem
\setbeamersize{text margin left = 15pt, text margin right = 15pt}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}
  {}
  {\vspace{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex} % Pads top of block
     % separates paragraphs in a block
   \setlength{\parskip}{24pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}
  {\vspace{2ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}}% Pads bottom of block
  {\vspace{10ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}} % Seperates blocks from each other


\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]{}


  \vspace{-8pt}
{\advance\textwidth40pt
 \hspace*{-20pt}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{}
    \maketitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
  \vspace{10ex}

  \begin{block}{Block A}
    \lipsum

    \begin{description}[longest label]
    \item[short] Short stuff
    \item[long] Longer stuff
    \item[longest label] Longest stuff (insert cat)
    \end{description}

     \begin{itemize}
     \item I'd like to change the margins here, as well.
     \item The macros \texttt{\textbackslash leftskip} and friends
       don't work very well for environment-heavy \LaTeX{} document
       classes such as \texttt{beamer}
     \item Also, for some \verb|$\log$| reason, using \texttt{\textbackslash verb}
       kills \emph{everthing}.
     \end{itemize}  
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `fragile` tip, that will definitely come in handy, but the hackiness is part of what I was trying to avoid.  Thanks though!

Comment: True but this is _far_ less hacky I just locally set the standard latex parameter textwidth to make the title box wider, and then recenter it with hspace. It's possible the title block has some key interface to that but it would do the same thing. The version in the question is the complete opposite: it globally set negative margins and then had to compensate everywhere. and set primitive tex registers such as left and right skip which breaks latex's typesetting structures as left and right margins and \textwidth \linewidth and \hsize were no longer matching

Comment: You're right, it is *by default* less hacky through the use of the local group, and solves the problem of the ripple effect from the root cause (the negative margins).  I shouldn't have unwittingly sneaked in two questions into one post, because this *does* help answer the 'how do I avoid this awful hack?' mini-question... :(